# Pushing golang app to cloud-foundry throws error in logs

Tags: go, manifest, cloud-foundry, go-gin

I have a go app in the `main.go` file which has a server. The server is running on `localhost:9090`.
I have my manifest.yaml:

```
applications:
  - name: golang-app
    buildpacks:
      - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack
    memory: 4GB
    disk_quota: 4GB
    instances: 1
    env:
      GO_APP_ENV: prod
    services:
      - go_mariadb-prod
```

When I push the app with `cf push -f manifest.prod.yaml`, everything seems to be working at first. Everything is beeing downloaded and built correctly.

But at the end it crashes and in the logs there is this error:

```
2023-03-07T14:14:13.86+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2023-03-07T14:14:14.50+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (6.8M)
   2023-03-07T14:14:14.50+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2023-03-07T14:14:14.92+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: ./main: No such file or directory
   2023-03-07T14:14:14.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 127
   2023-03-07T14:14:14.93+0100 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2023-03-07T14:14:20.21+0100 [API/1] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2023-03-07T14:14:20.22+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Cell b8118f92-f568-41d6-a3a1-125361b0d5c2 stopping instance d0442bce-ea3e-4c23-5c08-6ac4
   2023-03-07T14:14:20.22+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Cell b8118f92-f568-41d6-a3a1-125361b0d5c2 destroying container for instance d0442bce-ea3e-4c23-5c08-6ac4
```

I cant't figure out whats wrong here. I tried so many things by changing the manifest.yaml or the push command. But nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

When using the go-buildpack you should stick to this [docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/go/index.html)

In general, I suggest using the [CF Binary-Buildpack](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/binary/index.html) (way faster).

You can just build the GO app as a linux binary (shown below) on your system and just push the binary and needed assets to CF then.

```
GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags '-s -w' -o main ./cmd/main.go
```